# How to move files from subdirectories to their parent directory?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have files in folders organized like this

```
c:\111\1\file.jpg
c:\222\2\file.jpg
c:\333\3\file.jpg
```

I am trying to move the files to their respective parent folder. So they will be placed like this.

```
c:\111\file.jpg
c:\222\file.jpg
c:\333\file.jpg
```

I tried

```
for %F in (c:\*\*\*.*) do move /Y %F c:\*\*.*
```

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly iterate through the subfolders, one path at a time:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /b') do (
    cd "%%i"
    for /f %%j in ('dir /a:d /b') do (
        move "%%j" ..\
    )
    cd ..
)
```

Comment: i placed that code in c:\ it just generated a long list of errors that look like this 'c:\>(move "test"\* . )
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.'

Comment: not sure what you mean. where should i place the batch file

Comment: Save this code as a new plain text document eg. "doit.cmd" and run it. Make REALLY sure that you want to run this in c:\, because usually you don't want to have files moved around like this in your \windows directory.

Comment: 1) create a new folder c:\thingstomove 2) move 111, 222 and all your organized folders to this directory 3) place doit.cmd in that directory c:\thingstomove 4) run it there 5) after it is complete, move your folders back from c:\thingstomove to c:\ and delete the folder c:\thingstomove (and the batch). That you shave your folders on c:\

Comment: i did that. it just gave me a long list of errors that look like this. 'The system cannot find the file specified.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.' and then deleted the bat file

Comment: and it acctually deleted files but didnt move them

Answer (score 0):

Just use `..`.

Put this batch file in the directory of the files to be acted on.

```
for %%a in (*) do (move "%%a" ..)
```

Make sure to use quotations on first parameter of `move`. The **batch file will move**, too

Comment: what do you mean. should i place it in c:\ ?

Comment: Place it in `C:\123\3` or wherever you want to use the `move`. This is a more manual way. I wouldn't use these commands in your `c` drive.

Comment: so i would have to make hundreds of batch files in that case for each subfolder. i was looking for a batch solution that would do it autimatically

Comment: do you have an automatic way.

Comment: I didn't know that you needed hundreds. This code is best for only about 10-20. I can post an answer for `Python` if you want to use a different program.

Comment: im not sure how to compile or use python. but if i dont find a solution then i will have to i guess.

Comment: You can also try `for /r . . .` to walk through directories.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
FOR /D /R %%D in ("*") DO (
FOR %%f IN ("%%D\*.*") DO move "%%D\%%~nxf" "%%D\.."
)
pause
```

**WARNING**, this will move all documents in the tree below the folder this batch-file is in 1 directory up

Comment: so which directory should i place the batch file?

Comment: C:, and it will move all files in C: a folder up. This includes files in for example C:\ProgramFiles\

Comment: i see. if i pick the files i want the batch to act on and place it in a seperate subfolder. eg c:\runbatch and place the batch file in c:\runbatch. if i do that , will it work?

Comment: Yes, it will work in that case. You place the batch-file in the folder, where you want all files below that folder to move up.

Comment: In that case you should mark it as correct by clicking the check to the left of it so people who look this up find it

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

`FOR /F %i IN ('dir /s /b *.jpg') DO move %i %~pi..\`

or this ... in case you'r inside a BATCH file:

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('dir /s /b *.jpg') DO move %%i %%~pi..\
```

Answer (score 0):

It is little bit late, But it will help those who need to move files in their respective parent folder from two level depth folder structure:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /b') do (
    cd "%%i"
    for /f %%j in ('dir /a:d /b') do (
        move "%%j"\* .
        cd "%%j"
        for /f %%k in ('dir /a:d /b') do (
            move "%%k"\* ..\
        )
        cd ..
    )
    cd ..
)
```

Thanks,
Ravi